# Android: get data inside an obsever in mvvm and add it to a list

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm using the following code to get data from the viewmodel, i want to return the list after getting the data inside the observer but it returns empty

```
 private fun showFirstTodo(): ArrayList<hitsobj> {
        var listRecipe: ArrayList<hitsobj> = ArrayList()
        var obj: MutableList<hitsobj?>? = null
        viewModel.getFirstTodo().observe(this, Observer {
           obj = it.hit
            for (receta in obj!!) {
                listRecipe.add(receta!!)
                //Log.e(TAG, listRecipe.toString())
            }
            
        })

      
       return listRecipe
    }
```

Comment: please don't add the android studio tag just because you're using it to develop your application, only make use of the tag if you're specifically asking about a feature regarding the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You are **always** returning an empty list in `showFirstTodo()` function, you need to perform whatever you want to do with the List value of the LiveData returned by `getFirstTodo()` in the `Observer` object you are registering, the code would be like this:

```
private fun registerObserver(){
    viewModel.getFirstTodo().observe(this, Observer {
        val theListOfObjects = it.hit
        //todo: here you utilize the list value of the LiveData in your view model whenever this list changes
    })
}
```